# Error Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.DateTime' on return

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, implicit-conversion

I trying to add a propriety into a class but I'm getting the error: Error Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.DateTime' on the else return.

```
public DateTime BookDate
        {
            get
            {
                if (this.PXP.BookDate.HasValue)
                {
                    return this.PXP.BookDate.Value;
                }
                else return "";
            }
        }
```

I am not sure what to return here. I have to return something or else I get the error: not all code paths return a value. BookDate is being called from another class:

```
 public JobPXP PXP { get; set; }
```

**I know this question is very simple.. and the answer is I was just missing the `?` after DataTime. Thank you everyone for their answers**

Comment: Make it nullable, and then just return in if.

Comment: Well what do you *want* to return if there's no value? We can't tell you what the behaviour should be...

Comment: try return null in else

Comment: @apomene `DateTime` is a non-nullable value type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public DateTime BookDate
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.PXP.BookDate.HasValue)
            {
                return this.PXP.BookDate.Value;
            }
            else return "";
        }
    }
```

From your code it looks like you want to pass empty date when this.PXP.BookDate.HasValue is false.

The error is for - else return ""; statement. You are trying to pass string in return statement.
Here is my suggestion (I am assuming this.PXP.BookDate is nullable DateTime as it looks from your code.)

```
public DateTime? BookDate
    {
        get
        {                
            return this.PXP.BookDate;                
        }
    }
```

Comment: thank you, I was simply missing the ? after DataTime. The value returned includes the time after the data. I tried changing the code to `return this.PXP.BookDate.Value.ToShortDateString();` but again it says I cannot convert from string to System.DataTime?

Comment: @user123456789: When you do a `ToShortDateString`, what else do you expect? Doesn't the word `string` in `ToShortDateString` ring a bell?

Comment: @Abhitalks yes I realize that. So how can I stop the time from displaying?

Comment: @Abhitalks I don't really understand how to change my code to include `var dateAndTime = DateTime.Now;  var date = dateAndTime.Date;` I tried changing it to ` return this.PXP.BookDate.Value.Date; ` but the time is still displaying

Answer (score 1):

> I am not sure what to return here

If you are not sure what to return, probably you want to return `null`. However, the problem is that `BookDate` property is `DateTime`, which does not allow `null`s. However, `Nullable<DateTime>`, or simply `DateTime?` does allow `null`s. Since `this.PXP.BookDate` is nullable, you can return it directly, like this:

```
public DateTime? BookDate {
    get {
        return this.PXP.BookDate;
    }
}
```

Another solution is to make a method that would get an optional `BookDate` if it exists, similar to `TryGetValue` method of `IDictionary<K,V>`:

```
public bool TryGetBookDate(out DateTime res) {
    res = this.PXP.BookDate ?? default(DateTime);
    return this.PXP.BookDate.HasValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`DateTime`can not be null, so you can't return `null`. A string is also an invalid option. You've basically got two options here:

Either return a specific value of `DateTime`, such as `DateTime.MinValue` (which is `01.01.0001`), or use a `Nullable<DateTime>` instead (equivalent to `DateTime?`).

This last approach will let you return a `Null` values instead of an actual date, but will change the signature of the method, which in turn, will require handling when calling the method.

You'll still have to handle special cases outside the method if you use `DateTime.MinValue` instead though, so I'd say it's up to you to choose what suits your situation best.

Answer (score 0):

Another Way:

```
public DateTime BookDate
        {
            get
            {
               DateTime dt = DateTime.MinValue;//you default datetime here
               DateTime.TryParse(Convert.ToString(this.PXP.BookDate.Value),out dt)
               return dt;  

            }
    }
```